# how to configure different request body for post and put call for same end point in django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using django-rest-framework and for an endpoint (i.e) api/v1/accounts for post-call I need all data should be sent mandatorily and for put call, not all fields are needed only the field that needs to be updated is alone, how can I configure serializer for this, or should I use different serializer for post and put call?

Comment: Have you read this, https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation

Comment: Make an update and create serializer And use the get serializer method. But FYI a put usually requires all fields. Patch is for updating select fields.